# Faster list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have two lists with elements as tuples.

```
lst1 = [(101, 201), (102, 203), (103, 204)]
lst2 = [(1, 101, 201), (2, 101, 202), (3, 102, 203), (4, 103, 204), (5, 103, 205)]
```

I need to output the first item in the tuple in the second list if second and third items match with the tuples in the first list. I am using list comprehension and getting the expected result, but I have close to million elements in both lists, so it is too slow.

```
out_lst = [x[0] for x in lst2 if (x[1], x[2]) in lst1]

# Output
[1, 3, 4]
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Could you check against `set(lst1)` (created *outside* the loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` as searching is constant time for `set` objects.

```
lst1 = [(101, 201), (102, 203), (103, 204)]
lst2 = [(1, 101, 201), (2, 101, 202), (3, 102, 203), (4, 103, 204), (5, 103, 205)]
set1 = set(lst1)
res = [x[0] for x in lst2 if (x[1], x[2]) in set1]
```